# File upload on shared hosting

Tags: web-hosting, php

Is it possible to upload a file of size 300+ MB on *shared hosting* such as host gator ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean via php, the hostgator limit is 64M as you can see in your cpanel in the section "Software/Services" and then look at "php.ini QuickConfig".

If you mean via ftp, there's no limit.

Answer (score 1):

If the PHP.ini [upload_max_filesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) is set to have a limit of 300MB or more then, yes. You need to ask the hosting company what their limits are set at before signing up for hosting with them.